# How to access validation error messages in RSpec files?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am writing up some code for my first Rails app and can't seem to find the best way to look up my validation errors so that I can easily put them in without repeating myself.

I would like to turn this:

```
let(:error_messages) { page.find 'div#error_explanation ul' }
specify { error_messages.should have_content "Name can't be blank" }
specify { error_messages.should have_content "Email can't be blank" }
specify { error_messages.should have_content "Email is invalid" }
specify { error_messages.should have_content "Password can't be blank" }
specify { error_messages.should have_content "Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)" }
specify { error_messages.should have_content "Email is invalid" }
```

Into something like this:

```
let(:error_messages) { page.find 'div#error_explanation ul' }
specify { error_messages.should have_content "errors.name_blank" }
specify { error_messages.should have_content "errors.email_blank" }
specify { error_messages.should have_content "errors.email_invalid" }
specify { error_messages.should have_content "errors.password_invalid" }
specify { error_messages.should have_content "errors.password_short" }
specify { error_messages.should have_content "errors.email_invalid" }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you already testing your model validations? If so, apologies.

Otherwise, you should consider using the errors_on helper and testing your models themselves, described [here on rspec's relish pages](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-4/docs/model-specs/errors-on). This approach will be both faster to execute and less brittle when markup changes.

```
describe ValidatingWidget do
  it "fails validation with no name (using error_on)" do
    ValidatingWidget.new.should have(1).error_on(:name)
  end
end
```